# Unrolling template for integer serialization

Tags: c++, templates, serialization

I'm still fairly new to templates and can't say I'm fully comfortable yet. Therefore my question.

I've written a loop unrolling template for a platform independent serialization of unsigned integers. The template looks like this:

```
template <class tUnsignedIntegerType, const uint8_t tByteIndex>
class SerializerT
 {
 public:

  inline static void serialize (const tUnsignedIntegerType fUnsignedInt, uint8_t (&fPayLoadDestinationBuffer)[sizeof(tUnsignedIntegerType)])
   {

   // Serialize the byte in MSB -> LSB order
   fPayLoadDestinationBuffer[tByteIndex] = (uint8_t) (0xff & (fUnsignedInt >> (tByteIndex << 3))); // << 3 == *8

   // Serialize the next byte in MSB -> LSB order
   SerializerT<tUnsignedIntegerType, tByteIndex - 1>::serialize(fUnsignedInt, fPayLoadDestinationBuffer);
   }
  };


template <class tUnsignedIntegerType>
class SerializerT<tUnsignedIntegerType, 0>
 {
 public:
  inline static void serialize (const tUnsignedIntegerType fUnsignedInt, uint8_t (&fPayLoadDestinationBuffer)[sizeof(tUnsignedIntegerType)])
   {

   // Serialize the LSB byte
   fPayLoadDestinationBuffer[0] = (uint8_t) (0xff & fUnsignedInt);
   }
 };
```

and the user interface is

```
template <class tUnsignedIntegerType>
inline void serializeInt(const tUnsignedIntegerType fInt, uint8_t (&fPayLoadDestinationBuffer)[sizeof(tUnsignedIntegerType)])
 {
 SerializerT<tUnsignedIntegerType, sizeof(tUnsignedIntegerType) - 1>::serialize(fInt, fPayLoadDestinationBuffer);
 }
```

A simple usage example:

```
const uint64_t u64 = 0x0ff0ffff0000f00f;
uint8_t u64PayLoad[8];
serializeInt(u64, u64PayLoad); 
// u64PayLoad now holds the serialized int in LSB->MSB order starting at index 0.
```

Everything seems to work ok. My question is if the usage of templates here is overkill compared to e.g. a template using standard run-time loop, which may be unrolled by the compiler. IOW, how much of the serialization will be done at compile time? I assume that the assignment to fPayLoadDestinationBuffer[tByteIndex] is runtime but what about the rest?

Oh, I'm also on C++ 11.

Comment: What's wrong with something like `template<std::unsigned_integral T>
constexpr std::array<uint8_t, sizeof(T)> Serialize(T value)
{
    std::array<uint8_t, sizeof(T)> result;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != sizeof(T); ++i)
    {
        result[i] = static_cast<uint8_t>((value >> (8 * i)) & 0xff);
    }
    return result;
}

constexpr auto Test = Serialize(0x01020304u);
static_assert(Test[0] == 0x04);
static_assert(Test[1] == 0x03);
static_assert(Test[2] == 0x02);
static_assert(Test[3] == 0x01);`

Comment: Yes Fabian, that is what I'm contemplating. Is there actually a difference between the two or are they essentially the same and other metrics such as less code becomes more important.

Comment: @Nilsie You can experiment at [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/).  This will let you see the code generated for different inputs.  Don't forget to enable optimisation!